# How to hide RangesSliders behind a Navdropdownbar?

Tags: css

I have a dropdown menu and my website has some `Range Sliders`
The problem is that the `Range Sliders` wont hide behind the dropdown menu.
Everything else gets hidden...

I didn't use any CSS for the `Range Sliders`

Here is the jsfiddlelink, because it would be too much code to include here.
https://jsfiddle.net/hv08ngf2/1/

**This is the code for the normal Navigationbar**

```
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    background-color:#5488D1;
    top: 0px;
    width:100%;
}
.links {
    margin-left: 35%;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
.navbar a {
    float: left;
    display: block;
    color: #f2f2f2;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 17px;
}
.navbar .icon {
    display: none;
}
```

**And this is the CSS for the dropdown menu, which will be created at a specific resolution.**

Note: I didnt include it in the Code here, because its not important.

```
.links {
        margin:0px;
        padding: 0px;
}
.navbar a {
        display:none;
        font-size: 14px;
}
.navbar a.icon {
      float: right;
      display: block;
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      top: 0;
      padding:16px; 
}

/* This CSS will be created after you click the ".icon" class */
.navbar.responsive .links {
        margin-top: 60px;
        margin-bottom: 0%;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.2);
        background-color:rgb(228, 189, 118);
        z-index:1000;
}
.navbar.responsive {position: fixed;}
.navbar.responsive a {
      float: none;
      display: block;
      text-align: left;
      z-index:1000;
}
.navbar.responsive a.icon {
        position: fixed;
        border: none!important;
}
```

Comment: Hi can you please post your HTML as well?

Comment: Should I create a jsfiddle? Cause its a lot

Comment: Sure that would be helpful

Comment: I included into the post, can you open it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just had `z-index: 1000` to .navbar class

Comment: WOW! I only added it to the dropdown class and didnt think to add it to .navbar class. Thank you very much!